# Backup log files in tomcat server by shell script with gzip command

Tags: linux, shell, tomcat

I have some logs file that were created in the tomcat application, I backup the files by shell script that performs contraction by gzip command, after contraction, although that already the old log files do not exist, they are still taking up memory and space in disk,
This depletes the resources of the disc!

This is the code of shell script:

```
mkdir /tmp/backUp
mv `find $TOMCATDIR/logs/*.log -mtime +3`  /tmp/backUp
cd  /tmp/backUp
gzip *
```

---

after the script is run, the files still exist in the disk(although they aren't open)

`lsof |grep "deleted"`

```
java       584       cg   9w     REG             253,7     2253  18317840 /app/jakarta/apache-tomcat-8.0.9_xxx/logs/back06.07/catalina.06-02.log (deleted)
java       584       cg  10w     REG             253, 7      881   18317446 /app/jakartaapache-tomcat-8.0.9_xxx/logs/back06.07/localhost.06-02.log (deleted)
.......
....
...
```

Comment: could you format your shell script.

Comment: Have you considered using log rotate ?

Answer (score 1):

Files are deleted from filesystem where is deleted any reference to this inode. Reference can be on disk (link in any directory), and.. from open applications. If you remove file - you only delete reference from disk, but - there is still reference from application.

You can "free" space in two ways then:

1. you can kill application which opened file.
2. you can truncate file.

If you know pid - look what files are open by this pid: `ls -l /proc/PID/fd` you see here links like:

```
undefine@uml:~$ ls -l /proc/18596/fd
razem 0
lrwx------ 1 undefine undefine 64 lut  1 00:06 0 -> /dev/pts/30
lrwx------ 1 undefine undefine 64 lut  1 00:06 1 -> /dev/pts/30
lrwx------ 1 undefine undefine 64 lut  1 00:05 2 -> /dev/pts/30
lr-x------ 1 undefine undefine 64 lut  1 00:06 3 -> /home/undefine/x (deleted)
lr-x------ 1 undefine undefine 64 lut  1 00:06 4 -> anon_inode:inotify
```

As you see - 3 fd is deleted. you can truncate it by command (for example):

```
undefine@uml:~$ :>/proc/18596/fd/3
undefine@uml:~$
```

Remember that if application read from this file - it can be dangerous to them. But - if it's only a log file - you can truncate it safetly.